# Is there any standalone application which would export WF4 designer functionality?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I read that it is possible to host WF4 designer in standalone application outside Visual Studio 2010, in fact I tried it too. But main problem with it is missing intelisence.

**Therefore the question:**

Does anyone know about whether there are open source (or not OS) projects which add this missing functionality to standalone WF4 designer? Even better if it's a universal ready-to-use application

Answer (score 0):

no, there is no such kind of software.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, there's a way to do this. You need WorkFlowDesignSurface. Checkout some samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480213.aspx).

Check this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153576(VS.90).aspx) also.

Comment: It's not about WF4. I was able to move WF flow designer out of Visual Studio 2010 for WF4 in a similar way it is presented in your tutorial, but it lacks of auto-completion making it completely unuseful.